# How to return an object in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that might return regular object or an http request object.

I have something like

```
var t = function() {
    var obj
    var test;
    //code to determine test value

//return object depends on test value, 
//if test is undefined, return regular obj, 
//if not make a http request.
    if (!test){
          return obj;
    }
    return getObj(url) 
        .then(function(obj){
            return obj
        })
}

var getObj = function() {
    return $http.get(url);    
}

var open = function() {
   //this won't work for regular object, it has to be http object
    return t()
        .then(function(obj) {
            return obj;
        })
}

var obj = open();
```

How to check if returned object is through http request or just a regular object?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly your issue is with the object returned by `t` is a promise or not to enable chaining. You could do always wrap the object with [`$q.when(obj)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) it will make sure object returned is always a promise and can be chained through. You need to make sure to inject `$q` the way you are doing `$http`. Or just wrap the test value itself with `var obj = $q.when(value)` and `return obj`.

```
var t = function() {
    var obj; 
    var test;
    //code to determine test value
    if (!test){
       return $q.when(obj); //<-- return $q.when
    }
    return getObj(url) 
        .then(function(obj){
            return obj
        })
}

var getObj = function() {
    return $http.get(url);    
}

var open = function() {
    //this will always work now on
    //return t(); should be enough as well
    return t()
        .then(function(obj) {
            return obj;
        })
}
```

> when(value):Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the type of t was a function or an object. In order for it to be called, it must be typed as a function.

```
//this won't work for regular object, it has to be http object
if( typeof t !== "function" ){
 //return; or handle case where t is a plain object
}
```

Comment: I guess he is talking about the promise object and non promise object. In case of non promise object `t().then()` invocation will fail.

Comment: @PSL - Yes, I was unsure what the intention of `open` was as well. Since the object is getting passed only from there, and since it was originally setup as `{}` perhaps it made sense to simply pass `t` in this case on again which is why I tried to indicate `//return;` in this answer. On the other hand, I also like your idea of wrapping the object in the promise which in this case is probably best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code

Pass a callback method

```
var t = function(cb) {
    var obj
    var test;
    //code to determine test value

//return object depends on test value, 
//if test is undefined, return regular obj, 
//if not make a http request.
    if (!test){
          cb(obj);
    }
    return getObj(url) 
        .then(function(obj){
           cb(obj)
        })
}

var getObj = function() {
    return $http.get(url);    
}

var open = function() {
   //this won't work for regular object, it has to be http object
    return t(function(obj) {
            // write code dependent on obj
        })
}

var obj = open();
```

Comment: The problem with passing around callback is that you lose the advantage of promises and promise chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether the return object has a promise object or not:

```
var open = function() {
    var result = t();
    //Verify whether the return object has a promise object or not
    if(angular.isObject(result.promise)
    return result
        .then(function(obj) {
            return obj;
        })
}
```

Comment: Calling a plain object will give you `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.