# Create promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to create a promise in Angular with the $q service.
It returns an object retrieved from a web service. If the object is in the cache, it returns it without calling the web service.

The problem is that the two resolves are getting called.

Maybe, Am I using a promise anti-pattern?

Here is my code:

```
    function returnMapAsync() {

  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (navigationMap) {
      resolve(navigationMap);
    } else {
      ServerRequest.getNavigationMap().then(function (data) {
        navigationMap = data.object;
        resolve(navigationMap);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: [Yes you are](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) - good that you've asked :-)

Comment: see also [How to return an object in my case?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28057294/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to wrap everything in the `$q()` call.  In order to *promisify* `navigationMap` use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when):

```
function returnMapAsync() {

    if (navigationMap) {
        return $q.when(navigationMap);
    }
    return ServerRequest.getNavigationMap();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap it into one more promise since `ServerRequest.getNavigationMap()` is a promise:

```
function returnMapAsync() {

    if (navigationMap) {
        return $q.resolve(navigationMap);
    } 

    return ServerRequest.getNavigationMap().then(function(data) {
        navigationMap = data.object;
        return navigationMap;
    });
}
```